# User Interface Design in Flex

Tags: apache-flex, user-interface, air

I'm familiar with Actionscript and Flex. But when it comes to design the interface in Flex, I find myself that do not know where to start. I like to know what are the online resources/books to create the cool user interfaces like TweekDeck and Adobe Digital Edition.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

UI like in the ones like TweetDeck are done by custom skins. You need to look into skinning of flex components. If you are using flex 4  i.e, the spark components, its more easier to skin them. Also you can use Flash Catalyst if you are finding it difficult to skin using Flash Builder.

Answer (score 3):

You have to have design skills to make cool interfaces. @jase21 is correct that the spark components are easier to use (once you understand how to do it, which may mean unlearning a lot of Flex 3 habits you may have acquired). But just being able to skin components doesn't mean you will have great-looking interfaces. If you don't have those skills yourself, try to hook up with a designer who can make the comps in Photoshop or another graphics program, then you can implement them in Flex.

Answer (score 1):

Look into Flex Catalyst.  It is still green -- not nearly as capable as Expression Blend on the Silverlight side -- but it is a pretty good start.  Catalyst is the tool that designers can use to apply their Illustrator/Photoshop art to the skins in your app.

Unfortunately a lot is not skinnable via Catalyst.  It is also one-way at this time (the two-way beta is far from being useful IMO) which makes the Dev/Designer workflow cumbersome at best.  That being said, I have an amazing looking app based on work my designer is doing in Catalyst.  It takes some work to get it over into your app, but it can be done, and the results can be fantastic.

Comment: It's a flipping shame Adobe has fallen behind Microsoft with Blend vs Catalyst, as you correctly pointed out, but it is what it is I guess. I wish Adobe would pay more attention to developer tools, project templating, and other ideas Microsoft seems to be great at coming up with.

Comment: Thanks Brian, took your advice and use catalyst to create the skin for button. It generated code for visual effects. It was more than I can ask for. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Flash Builder has a "design view" mode... although honestly ever since version 4 it has been a little picky and buggy.

Without that, you could try this, but I've no idea how it is: 
http://flexible.riaforge.org/

Basically these are WYSIWYG gui editors, drag and drop components into a preview screen. They're nice when they work correctly, but it's tough to do.

Comment: Going to update a bit - FB4 design mode, not so picky once you get used to the (new) quirks.  And still, it's much better than anything I've seen the competition do (and I've looked).  I guess the grass is always greener over the hill, but Flex is a good side of the hill to be on.